# populate connection tables with sqlalchemy ORM for a complex schema

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to import a complex data set of regulatory classifications into a new database. The complexity comes from having disparate kinds of classifiers being assigned to the same classified objects. There are hierarchical (one-to-many) "Categories" and non-hierarchical (many-to-many) "Attributes" with an assigned range of values for each "Attribute". The problem is with populating data. Since non-hierarchical "Attributes" are not the same for each of the lowest "Categories", simply marking a `secondary` relationship attribute and an `a.append(b)` is not going to produce the desired input for connection tables. JSON would be a good format for this, but it's not feasible due to a high number of records. I'm looking for the best way to retain and populate the schema offered below. Here's a simplified example:

```
Supercat  Category  Subcategory Attr.Type Attribute  Attr.Value

Vertebrae Mammals   Cats        Color     Hair Color Blue
                                          Hair Color Black
                                          Eye Color  Blue
                                          Eye Color  Green
                                Magic     Yes/No     Maybe
                                Legs      Count      4
                                Habitat   Land/Sea   Land
                    Dogs        Color     Hair Color Brown
                                          Hair Color Black
                                          Eye Color  Blue
                                          Eye Color  Green
                                Magic     Yes/No     No
                                Legs      Count      4
                                Tailwags  Happy      Yes
                                          Unhappy    No
                                Habitat   Land/Sea   Land
                    Whales      Color     Skin Color Blue
                                          Skin Color Grey
                                Habitat   Land/Sea   Sea
                    Unicorns    Color     Hair Color Rainbow
                                Magic     Yes/No     Yes
                                Habitat   Land/Sea   Unknown
                                Legs      Count      4
                                          Hooves     Yes
          Fish      Sharks      Color     Skin Color White
                                          Skin Color Grey
                                Magic     Yes/No     No
                                Habitat   Land/Sea   Sea
                    Goldfish    Color     Scales     Gold
                                Habitat   Land/Sea   Sea
```

Here's the SQLAlchemy ORM representation of the schema for this getup:

```
#connection tables:
attribute_type_attributes = db.Table('attribute_type_attributes',
    db.Column('type_id', db.ForeignKey('attribute_types.id'), ...),
    db.Column('attribute_id', db.ForeignKey('attributes.id'), ...)
)

attribute_values_attributes = db.Table('attribute_type_attributes',
    db.Column('type_id', db.ForeignKey('attribute_types.id'), ...),
    db.Column('value_id', db.ForeignKey('attribute_values.id'), ...)
)

subcategory_attribute_types = db.Table('subcategory_attribute_types',
    db.Column('type_id', db.ForeignKey('attribute_types.id'), ...),
    db.Column('subcat_id', db.ForeignKey('subcats.id'), ...)
)

subcategory_attributes = db.Table('subcategory_attributes',
    db.Column('type_id', db.ForeignKey('attributes.id'), ...),
    db.Column('subcat_id', db.ForeignKey('subcats.id'), ...)
)

subcategory_attribute_values = db.Table('subcategory_attribute_values',
    db.Column('type_id', db.ForeignKey('attribute_values.id'), ...),
    db.Column('subcat_id', db.ForeignKey('subcats.id'), ...)
)
```

```
#models:
class Supercat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(...)
    name = db.Column(...)

class Cat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(...)
    supercat_id = db.Column(..., db.ForeignKey('supercats.id'), ...)
    name = db.Column(...)

class Subcat(db.Model):
    id = db.model(...)
    cat_id = db.Column(..., db.ForeignKey('cats.id'), ...)
    name = db.Column(...)

class Attribute_type(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_types'
    id = db.Column(...)
    name = db.Column(...)

class Attribute(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'
    id = db.Column(...)
    name = db.Column(...)

class Attribute_value(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_values'
    id = db.Column(...)
    name = db.Column(...)
```

Once again, different hierarchical "Categories" have different non-hierarchical "Attributes", and they correlate to different sets of values. I cannot have the non-hierarchical "Attributes" or their values related to the wrong "Subcategory" because the data are not mine to alter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There are references to `attribute_types.id` and `attributes.id` in your list of tables but those tables aren't included. Can you include the entire schema?

Comment: I've now shown `__tablename__` class attributes in the existing schema. These were implied given the class names. Most other details are still omitted in order to focus on the generic solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy, i was expecting to see all the relevant tables/columns specified in the first section (e.g. `#connection tables:`) and/or just the underlying SQL DDL.

Answer (score 1):

To store the category hierarchy you could use 3 tables (super-cat, cat, sub-cat) as you currently have or a single table (category w/ parent_category_id). I'd probably use a single table but separate tables also seems fine.

Then have a table to store the kinds of attributes (e.g. 'Hair color') in an
`attributes` table with `id`, `attribute_type`, and `name` columns. You can either store `attribute_type` as a string (e.g. `Color`) or as a reference to an `attribute_types` table that stores the name `Color`.

Finally, to store the attribute values for each sub-category I would have a table (e.g. `subcategory_attributes`) that references both the sub-category table and the attributes table and stores the `value` (e.g. 'Blue'). You can also pull out the `values` into their own table and just reference them if you want to further normalize the data/if it makes sense.

Here's some terrible ascii art depicting the schema.

```
[ super-categories ]      [  attribute_types (name:Color)    ]
        ^                                    ^
        |                                    |
[   categories     ]      [     attributes (name:Hair color) ]
        ^                                    ^
        |                                    |
[  subcategories   ]  <-- [ subcategory_attributes (value:Blue) ]
```

Maybe I'm missing something but I think I'm missing the difficulty in associating one or more attribute-values (that have a specific attribute type, etc) with a specific sub-category.

Comment: Thank you! This was my first schema, including the normalized `attribute_values` relation. I am, however, having a problem associating the `attribute` relation and `attribute_type` relation with `subcategories` in this case. I don't see the way of populating the connection tables between these relations, and I need them to allow users to identify `attribute_type` and `attribute` related to a `subcategory`.  The caveat is that values are not unique between `attributes`, so the lower right relationship in your schema will not suffice. An alternative one-to-many hierarchy of values is too complex

Comment: Once I identify the `attribute`, isn't the `attribute_type` implied? e.g. if I choose `Hair Color` isn't the type always `Color`? Why do I need to choose both?

Comment: " I don't see the way of populating the connection tables between these relations" is that a limitation of SQLAlchemy? Can you provide more detail of what challenge you're having populating the connection tables?

Comment: The `type` for HairColor `attribute` is always Color in this case, but it can be Hair, and there's a YesNo `attribute` that belongs to a large number of `types`. So, the user selection has to start at the `type` level. As to the challenge of populating connection tables, I cannot figure out a way to plug data without creating a monstrously large JSON and looping through each level to assign connection tuples to appropriate relations. Perhaps I need to resign to this eventuality and just do this, but I was hoping somebody could enlighten me about sqlalchemy capabilities beyond my current grasp.